# If $f(z)$ is continuous and nonzero at a point $z=z_0$, then there is a neighbourhood of $z=z_0$ in which $f(z)$ is nonzero.

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification

Here is my proof. (Note that $z$ refers to complex number.)

Since $f(z)$ is continuous at $z=z_0$, by definition, for any $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $|f(z)-f(z_0)| <\epsilon$ whenever $|z-z_0|<\delta$. (or equivalently, there exists a neighbourhood $N(z_0;\delta)$.)

Then for $\epsilon=|f(z_0)|>0$ ($|f(z_0)|\neq 0$ as $f(z_0)\neq 0$), there exists $N(z_0;\delta)$ such that

$$\big||f(z)|-|f(z_0)|\big|\leq |f(z)-f(z_0)|<\epsilon$$
$$\Rightarrow\big||f(z)|-|f(z_0)|\big|<\epsilon$$
$$\Rightarrow -\epsilon+|f(z_0)|<|f(z)|<\epsilon+|f(z_0)|$$
$$\Rightarrow 0<|f(z)|<2|f(z_0)|$$
$$\Rightarrow |f(z)|>0$$
$$\Rightarrow f(z)\neq 0$$
as required.

Is my proof correct?

Comment: Yea it's fine .

Answer (score 1):

Assume the contradiction and in the definition of continuity, take $\epsilon=\alpha |P(z_0)|$ for  a fixed $\alpha$ with $|\alpha|<1.$ Since $f(z)$ vanishes for some value of $z$ in every nhd of $f(z_0)$ we will have a situation 
$|f(z_0)|<|\alpha f(z_0)|,$ a contradiction.