# Proving that a set of holomorphic functions is a field

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $ M_{\alpha,r} $ be the set of holomorphic functions $ f $ on the punctured disk $D(\alpha,r)\setminus{\alpha} $ such that $\alpha $ is not an essential singularity for $ f $. From the uniquness principle, if $r'<r $ then the restriction of functions map $M_{\alpha,r} \to M_{\alpha,r'} $ is injective

I want to show that $ K_{\alpha}=\bigcup_{r>0}M_{\alpha,r} $ is the field for the operations induced from pointwise sum and product (on small enough disk).

Now my problem is with finding an inverse to $ f $ in relation to the product. For given $ f $ I need to find a disk where $ f $ does not vanish in order to define the inverse, and my first thought was to say " there has to be a disk where $ f $ does not vanish, otherwise its identical zero due to uniquness theorem", but, the point $\alpha $ is not in the set so uniquness theorem cannot be used (we need the accumulation point in the set).

How can I prove that there exist an inverse for $ f\neq 0 $ in the set?

Comment: It is always possible to find such a disk. Your choice of set $K_\alpha$ is unusual, is not the germ around $\alpha$ is a more appropriate choice of underlying set? I.e. one needs to pass through to an appropriate quotient to get a field. (Unless that is what you mean  implicitly  by the bracketed comment (on a small enough disk))

Comment: Anyhow, the claim you seek is proved by the asker in this post, note that only continuity of $f$  near $\alpha$ is required: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2945214/if-fz-is-continuous-and-nonzero-at-a-point-z-z-0-then-there-is-a-neighbou

Comment: @user2628206 how? in my case the function is not even defined at $\alpha $

Comment: True,  and good point. If $f$ is defined at $\alpha$, one is done by given result. Otherwise, $f$ has a pole of some order at $\alpha$. Thus if follows that $\lim_{z \to \alpha}\left|f(z)\right| = \infty$. A similar argument to the prior case gives a disk around $\alpha$ whereby $f$ is nonzero. Can you complete the argumentation from here or  do you need a full answer writing up?

Comment: @user2628206 what if $ f $ i defined in $\alpha $ and is $0 $ there?

Comment: Then $z=\alpha$ must be an isolated zero of $f$ (do you see why?) and you can still find a punctured disk around $\alpha$ where $f$ is holomorphic and has no zeros.

Comment: Either $f$ is the zero function on some domain containing $\alpha$, or there is some unique minimal $n \in \mathbb N$ such that $\frac{f(z)}{(z - \alpha)^n}$ has a nonzero limit approaching $\alpha$, you can then argue that an inverse exists. I realise now that this question is a little tricky - I may write up a full solution later should  no-one beat me to it

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen gives a potentially easer way of thinking about it

Comment: Thanks, I fully understand the proof now.